# Cannot install uWSGI on Mac os X 10.9.5

Tags: python, macos, uwsgi

When I'm trying to install uWSGI in Mac OS X 10.9.5 I get the following error:

```
Installing collected packages: uwsgi
  Running setup.py install for uwsgi
    plugins/python/pyutils.c:14:22: error: equality comparison with extraneous parentheses [-Werror,-Wparentheses-equality]
     if (((exc)->ob_type == &PyClass_Type)) {
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    plugins/python/pyutils.c:14:22: note: remove extraneous parentheses around the comparison to silence this warning
     if (((exc)->ob_type == &PyClass_Type)) {
         ~               ^               ~
    plugins/python/pyutils.c:14:22: note: use '=' to turn this equality comparison into an assignment
     if (((exc)->ob_type == &PyClass_Type)) {
                         ^~
                         =
    1 error generated.
    Complete output from command /Users/jakob/.virtualenvs/uwsgi/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/Users/jakob/.virtualenvs/uwsgi/build/uwsgi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/sk/51hn9dcn0b9g6mggg4wkmb6w0000gp/T/pip-p4efMm-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/jakob/.virtualenvs/uwsgi/include/site/python2.7:
```

I'm running inside a virtualenv, using Python 2.7.5, tried to upgrade pyutils. Any ideas?

Here is the full log:

```
~/t/uwsgi $ vf new uwsgi                                                                                                                                                 
New python executable in /Users/jakob/.virtualenvs/uwsgi/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
(uwsgi) ~/t/uwsgi $ python --version                                                                                                                                      
Python 2.7.5
(uwsgi) ~/t/uwsgi $ pip install uwsgi                                                                                                                                    
Downloading/unpacking uwsgi
  Real name of requirement uwsgi is uWSGI
  Using download cache from /Users/jakob/.pip/cache/pypi%2Fpackages%2Fsource%2Fu%2FuWSGI%2Fuwsgi-2.0.7.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/Users/jakob/.virtualenvs/uwsgi/build/uwsgi/setup.py) egg_info for package uwsgi

Installing collected packages: uwsgi
  Running setup.py install for uwsgi
    plugins/python/pyutils.c:14:22: error: equality comparison with extraneous parentheses [-Werror,-Wparentheses-equality]
     if (((exc)->ob_type == &PyClass_Type)) {
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    plugins/python/pyutils.c:14:22: note: remove extraneous parentheses around the comparison to silence this warning
     if (((exc)->ob_type == &PyClass_Type)) {
         ~               ^               ~
    plugins/python/pyutils.c:14:22: note: use '=' to turn this equality comparison into an assignment
     if (((exc)->ob_type == &PyClass_Type)) {
                         ^~
                         =
    1 error generated.
    Complete output from command /Users/jakob/.virtualenvs/uwsgi/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/Users/jakob/.virtualenvs/uwsgi/build/uwsgi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/sk/51hn9dcn0b9g6mggg4wkmb6w0000gp/T/pip-p4efMm-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/jakob/.virtualenvs/uwsgi/include/site/python2.7:
    running install

plugins/python/pyutils.c:14:22: error: equality comparison with extraneous parentheses [-Werror,-Wparentheses-equality]

 if (((exc)->ob_type == &PyClass_Type)) {

      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

plugins/python/pyutils.c:14:22: note: remove extraneous parentheses around the comparison to silence this warning

 if (((exc)->ob_type == &PyClass_Type)) {

     ~               ^               ~

plugins/python/pyutils.c:14:22: note: use '=' to turn this equality comparison into an assignment

 if (((exc)->ob_type == &PyClass_Type)) {

                     ^~

                     =

1 error generated.

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /Users/jakob/.virtualenvs/uwsgi/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/Users/jakob/.virtualenvs/uwsgi/build/uwsgi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/sk/51hn9dcn0b9g6mggg4wkmb6w0000gp/T/pip-p4efMm-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/jakob/.virtualenvs/uwsgi/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /Users/jakob/.virtualenvs/uwsgi/build/uwsgi
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/jakob/.pip/pip.log

(uwsgi) ~/t/uwsgi $ pip freeze                                                                                                                                           
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `export CC=/usr/bin/llvm-gcc` made it work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Yup, it is an answer. By running `export CC=/usr/bin/llvm-gcc` and then `pip install uwsgi` it works.

Answer (score 5):

Use `brew install uwsgi` maybe is a good choice and worked for me.

ref: http://macappstore.org/uwsgi/

Answer (score 1):

If you have anaconda environment
You can use `conda install -c conda-forge uwsgi`

[Conda doc](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/uwsgi)